# udev rule not executing the script specified in RUN

Tags: linux, rhel, systemd, udev, hardware

I have the following in `/etc/udev/rules.d/40-swallowpv.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]+", RUN="/var/tmp/swallowpv sdc"
```

(I've also tried with `RUN+=` to the same effect).

The first thing the script does is run `logger` to notify that it's started but this notification is never received. I've made sure the permissions match other rules that do seem to run and I'm not seeing any obvious errors (either syntax or in messages/journalctl). After editing I did a `udevadm control --reload-rules` but adding a disk to the system (`sdc` to start) completes successfully but the `logger` command in the script doesn't seem to ever execute.

For the script itself, it's `root:root` for ownership and I started out with `0700` but I've also tried `0777` to no avail. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled and enforcing?  You might be tripping over enforcement rules; this may be logged in `dmesg` or files in `/var/log`.

Comment: No on dmesg and selinux

Comment: @StephenHarris The problem appears to be due to the regex. This rule works: `ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]", RUN="/var/tmp/swallowpv %k"`

Comment: You should add that as an answer :-)

Comment: `udev` rules are more like globs, not regex's - http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#strmatch

Comment: @StephenHarris so there's no way to say "same character class `x` number of times" ?

Comment: Reading that makes it sound like it would catch everything, including numbers, which isn't what I want.